# LogFactory$1 does not implement the requested interface java.security.PrivilegedAction

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, logging

Java version 14
gradle version 6.6.1 and 6.8.3

I have a library project where we have libraries like spring-boot-starter-web (excluded module logbck-classic), spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, hibernate-core, lombok etc.
I DO NOT have spring-boot-starter-logging.

I am able to build this library project and publish to local maven repository.

Then I use this in another springboot project and that build is also successful.

When I attempt to run it using the command

`java -jar build/libs/project.jar`

I get this exception, and this is the only output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
         at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
         at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107)
         at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
         at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
 Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$1 does not implement the requested interface java.security.PrivilegedAction
         at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
         at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getContextClassLoaderInternal(LogFactory.java:808)
         at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getFactory(LogFactory.java:419)
         at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:196)
         at com.something.autoendorsement.AutoEndorsementApplication.main(AutoEndorsementApplication.java:16)
         ... 8 more
```

I was able to find similar errors on the internet but completely unrelated.

Weird part is that when i run the project using intellij, everything works fine.

One more weird part is that as of today I am using a version of this library that works just fine even with the java -jar command, but if a just release a new version of this with any small change, I start getting this error. So there must be something wrong during the build process itself.

There is just too much code that I can't really share in a post, so if you have any leads or hints on how I can go about figuring out a solution for this that'll be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case , check your dependencies tree, there might be two different dependencies for logging and thats why they are creating inconsistency in your situation.
run:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

if you are using wrapper,
replace app with project module name.

and

```
gradle dependencies
```

with modules